# Importing big Excel file to Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to import a big `xlsx` file to `Mathematica 9`, but I always get the error

> Import::nojmem: There was insufficient Java heap space for the
>   operation. Try increasing the Java Virtual Machine heap size.

Increasing heap size isn't helping.

I also tried to save my file as `csv` but the output is a long list of values. How can I import my file correctly or how can I convert this list to the matrix form? Thanks.

Comment: sorry know help, but the java error is a known bug.

Comment: What is the problem with importing the CSV?

Comment: some discussion here.. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/importing-a-large-excel-file